# Bad Request: Twitter API Upload Image

Tags: c#, twitter, multipartform-data

I have a requirement to post image to Twitter via their REST API. I referred [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) documentation and came up with below solution to frame the request. I am creating a multipartformdatacontent object and populating with byte array of the file. But, on Post, the response is recieved as `400 Bad Request`. What can be the issue here? Please let me know.

```
System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\somelocalpath", 
                                      System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                      System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bytearray = new Byte[fileStream.Length];
fileStream.Close();

var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytearray);
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
multipartContent.Add(imageContent, "media");

responseTask = await _client.PostAsync("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", multipartContent);
```

PS: I am attaching all authorization params to the request (which work fine on get requests, so should be good here as well)

Comment: Your `bytearray` contains numbers of zero bytes.

Comment: Yes, I just debugged and I can see that bytearray has only zero bytes. But, how is this possible? The file has .jpg extension which is allowed by twitter. What can be causing this?

Comment: Also, fileStream.length is correct in this case, which is the size of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your byte array like below

```
byte[] bytearray = File.ReadAllBytes(yout file Name);
```

Also you may like to set content length before making post call.

Comment: Oh, I guess i somehow missed to read the input file. My bad. Thanks!